# Create a tree from a list of Objects containing paths in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to create a folder tree using a list of objects that contain paths. This solution is working only for a list of strings(paths), but I don't know how to make it work using objects.

```js
    var paths = ["About.vue", "Categories/Index.vue", "Categories/Demo.vue", "Categories/Flavors.vue", "Categories/Types/Index.vue", "Categories/Types/Other.vue"],
            result = paths.reduce((r, p) => {
              var names = p.split("/");
              names.reduce((q, name) => {
                var temp = q.find(o => o.name === name);
                if (!temp) {
                  q.push((temp = { name, children: [] }));
                }
                return temp.children;
              }, r);
              return r;
            }, []);

            console.log(result)
```

I want to do the same but instead of using an array of paths using an array of objects that contains paths.

From an array like this:

```
var paths = [{
  path: "/media",
  id: 9,
  name:"media"
},{
  path: "/media/folder1",
  id: 1,
  name:"folder1"
},{
  path: "/media/folder1/child",
  id: 3,
  name: "child"
},
{
  path: "/media/folder2",
  id: 2,
  name: "folder2"
}];
```

I want something like this:

```
 [
  {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "media",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "folder1",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "child",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "folder2",
        "children": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Your input and expected output don't match (input root folder is media, output root folder is applications etc.). Can you either change the input or the output so that they match, please? Then I can ensure I give you the correct output for a given input.

Comment: The output is just an example of what I want, the real output is in the code snippet I made @AlexL

Comment: Yeah ok, but the point is, a good question has a stated input and a stated expected output. So in your case, keep it consistent and choose one input to reference and one matching output to reference, make sense? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @AlexL output updated

Comment: Perfect  and my answer gives this output :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the example code you gave, you just need to change one line:

`const [root, ...names] = p.path.split("/");`

and add another line:

`const id = p.name == name ? p.id : undefined;`

and change one final line:

`q.push((temp = { id, name, children: [] }));`

```js
const paths = ["About.vue", "Categories/Index.vue", "Categories/Demo.vue", "Categories/Flavors.vue", "Categories/Types/Index.vue", "Categories/Types/Other.vue"];

const paths2 = [
  {
  path: "/media",
  id: 9,
  name:"media"
},{
  path: "/media/folder1",
  id: 1,
  name:"folder1"
},{
  path: "/media/folder1/child",
  id: 3,
  name: "child"
},
{
  path: "/media/folder2",
  id: 2,
  name: "folder2"
}];

const out1 = createTree(paths);
const out2 = createTree(paths2);

function createTree(input){
  const result = input.reduce((r, p, i) => {
    if (!(p instanceof Object)){
      p = {path: p, id: i};
    }
    const path = p.path && p.path.substr(0,1) == "/"
                ? p.path
                : "/" + p.path;
    const [root, ...names] = path.split("/");
    const last = names[names.length - 1];
    names.reduce((q, name) => {
      let temp = q.find(o => o.name === name);
      //const id = p.name == name ? p.id : undefined;
      const id = last == name ? p.id : undefined
      if (!temp) {
        q.push((temp = { id, name, children: [] }));
      }
      return temp.children;
    }, r);
    return r;
  }, []);
  console.log(result)
  return result;
}
```

Output:

```js
[
  {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "media",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "folder1",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "child",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "folder2",
        "children": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: But after modifying that how can I get the id from the object in the `q.push((temp = { name, children: [] }));` method?

Comment: I made the changes needed to include the id in my updated answer, does that work?

Comment: No, this is not working, it only adds the id to the last childs of the tree, the rest are showing undefined values

Comment: The only undefined it assigns is to ``{name: "media"}`` because from your data, how am I supposed to know what id that has? Should i generate it randomly? All other items have the correct id, right?

Comment: Even adding the **/media** route to the array It gives undefined value for some reason. I tested the code here [link](https://playcode.io/621066/)

Comment: Shouldn't the name of the first item be "media" (to be consistent with how the others are named)? See my updated answer - no undefined ids, when we rename that one to ``{name: "media"}`` also here - https://playcode.io/621079/

Comment: Otherwise, we can change the code to handle it differently, so that instead of matching id when part of the path is equal to the name property, we match id when the part of the path is equal to the final part of the path.

Comment: The answer is now more flexible, doesn't require the "name" property and will handle string or object input.